# How do I write my Postgres query to return the value that is occuring with the maximum frequency in a particular column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables in my database that have information for movie tickets (whose columns are movie ID and ticket ID) and for movie screenings (whose columns are movie title, ticket ID, and show time). I am trying to write an PSQL query that allows me to figure out which specific show time is the most popular (i.e. which show time occurs with the highest frequency in the show time column)

To illustrate, I have so far written my query to return the show times of a particular movie (e.g. 20:20, 13:00) based on the movie's ID being 15.

```
SELECT show_time FROM screenings
      INNER JOIN tickets
      ON screenings.ticket_id = tickets.id
      WHERE screenings.film_id = 15
```

Let's pretend that this query returns a series of times such as 20:20, 18:05, 13:00, 20:20. Now, I want to expand this query so it returns the one show time that occurred most frequently in the results (which would be 20:20 in this case). I have tried using a few different approaches, but none of them have worked yet. I tried entering the above as a subquery like:

```
SELECT MAX(*) FROM
      (SELECT COUNT(show_time)
      FROM screenings
      INNER JOIN tickets
      ON screenings.ticket_id = tickets.id
      WHERE screenings.film_id = 15)
```

But then I get the error:

```
ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias
LINE 2:    (SELECT COUNT(show_time)
           ^
HINT:  For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.
```

I have tried researching this topic and putting in an alias, but I'm not familiar enough with PSQL to structure the query correctly. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using analytic functions:

```
SELECT show_time
FROM (SELECT show_time, COUNT(*) as cnt,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM screenings s JOIN
           tickets t
           ON s.ticket_id = t.id
      WHERE s.film_id = 15
      GROUP BY show_time
     ) st
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Awesome! But can I ask, what is the purpose of seqnum in this context? Would it just be numbering the counts of each show time from highest to lowest and then selecting out only the top count with `where seqnum = 1`?

Comment: @BobMcBobson . . . Yes.  That is what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `mode()` function:

```
SELECT mode() within group (order by show_time) as most_frequent_show_time
FROM screenings
  JOIN tickets ON screenings.ticket_id = tickets.id
WHERE screenings.film_id = 15;
```